# Retaining 1 core data entity and update a second one. Is it possible?

Tags: core-data

I hope this makes sense (Im self taught with IOS) I have a coredata entity where all but 3 attributes are pre-loaded information that will ship with the App. The 3 empty attributes are for the User to add and persist their own information. I got all this working and thought "Happy Days" but then I discovered that when you perform a data model update in IOS, the existing data is all deleted.

So, Basically I would like a way to be able to replace/update the pre-loaded attributes and retain the 3 attributes that have been created and persisted by the user. Is there a way to do this? Would you save the 3 attributes into a separate temporary file then replace the entire Entity and then read the temporary file back into the Entity ? If so Ive no idea how to achieve this!! Or should I have a separate Entity with just the 3 attributes for the user to write and save to and link with a to-one relationship? If this is the answer can you replace one entity and leave the other untouched? Or should I go down the route of 2 data models? Many thanks in advance for any light on the matter. many thanks Jon

Sorry I slightly worded my question inaccurately. I can see that Light Weight Migration sorts out "model" changes but does it handle Data changes within the models? What I would like to do is add new updated "data" changes to "some" of the attributes and also allow the preservation of other attributes (the 3 the user has entered) within the same entity? It kind of like half of the attributes-data are replaced with updated data and the other half are retained with their existing data and the 2 merge into one new model. If it can do this then thats truly awesome and sorts out my query. Thanks again for answering, I really appreciate it. Jon

Answer (score 0):

Just use Lightweight Migration, described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html). All data will be preserved.

Comment: Many thank Mundi, Ive just refined my question slightly as Id like some data replaced and some saved. Hopefully you can let me know if thats possible. I really appreciate it. Cheers Jon